# How to add any HTML tag that starts with a string to IntrinsicElements?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my Jest tests I mock React components like this:

```
jest.mock('../../../components/MyComponent', () => 
  ({ __esModule: true, default: props => <mock-component {...props} /> }))
```

TypeScript (4.8.4) doesn't like it because it isn't a standard HTML tag which is fair but when I try to add it, it doesn't like it:

```
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            [htmlTag: `mock-${string}`]: any,
            // 'mock-foo': any
        }
    }
}
```

```
Property 'mock-foo' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

If I comment out that line to declare the specific new HTML tag it works correctly.

Sandbox: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCgEyTQBsUi4BzOiAIxTrgG8KBIAHYoQSAM5h0SOACkAygA1eA-sEEwkUTFLgBJdVDVjgaAKJ0ko9WOXl+9gNoALGCDoAVFMwBccAAYgEGgA1gC0ACQ8YjCGgswAvn4Aur4oggCeADQq-AD0uQSBIaGYEBD4qRkq8QI15HUUaBCC0XAAsukAwriQgkjqcAC8cAAUAJRDAHxwADxFYaUQcLmTFEA

How do I fix this without manually specifying every single "fake" HTML tag or adding `@ts-ignore` to my test files?